# C# & LINQ, Select two (consecutive) items at once

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ on an ordered set (array, list), is there a way to select or otherwise use two consecutive items? I am imagining the syntax:

```
list.SelectTwo((x, y) => ...)
```

Where `x` and `y` are the items at index `i` and `i + 1` in the list/array.
There may be no way to do this, which I accept as a possibility, but I would at least like to say I tried to find an answer.

I am aware that I could use something other and LINQ to achieve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: LINQ is just extensions methods on IEnumerables. You could very easily implement this yourself if the end goal is just to be able to use it in a LINQ-y way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35327578/1892179) presents a nice and clean solution using LINQ's `Skip` and `Zip`.

It is absolutely correct, but I'd like to point out that it enumerates the source twice. That may or may not matter, depending on each individual use case. If it matters for your case, here's a longer alternative that is functionally equivalent but enumerates the source once:

```
static class EnumerableUtilities
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTwo<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                                   Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));

        return SelectTwoImpl(source, selector);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTwoImpl<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                                        Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var item2 = default(TSource);
            var i = 0;
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var item1 = item2;
                item2 = iterator.Current;
                i++;

                if (i >= 2)
                {
                    yield return selector(item1, item2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
var seq = new[] {"A", "B", "C", "D"}.SelectTwo((a, b) => a + b);
```

The resulting sequence contains `"AB"`, `"BC"`, `"CD"`.

Answer (score 7):

`System.Linq.Enumerable.Zip` combines two `IEnumerable`s by pairing up the `i`-th element for each `i`. So you just need to `Zip` your list with a shifted version of it.

As a nice extension method:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class ExtMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTwo<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
                                                                        Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        return Enumerable.Zip(source, source.Skip(1), selector);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Enumerable.Range(1,5).SelectTwo((a,b) => $"({a},{b})");
```

Results in:

```
(1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5)
```

Comment: I didn't know about this. This is great! I'd only point out that it enumerates the source twice, which may or may not be desirable (depending on the case).

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
list.Skip(i).Take(2)
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<T>` with only the two consecutive items.

Comment: I don't think this is what was asked for (although the question is a bit vague)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can select item and next item data in an ordered list like this:

```
var theList = new List<T>();
theList
    .Select((item, index) => new { CurrIndex = index, item.Prop1, item.Prop2, theList[index + 1].Prop1 })
    .Where(newItem => {some condition on the item});
```

However, `index` of the selected items should be less than list size - 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special overload of `Select` that allows you to use the index of the item, and the `GroupBy` method to split the list into groups. Each group would have two items. Here is an extension method that does that:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTwo<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        return source.Select((item, index) => new {item, index})
            .GroupBy(x => x.index/2)
            .Select(g => g.Select(i => i.item).ToArray())
            .Select(x => selector(x[0], x[1]));
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var list = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var result = list.SelectTwo((x, y) => x + y).ToList();
```

This would return {3,7,11}

Please note that the above method groups the data in memory before starting to yield results. If you have large data sets, you might want to have a streaming approach (yield data as the data from the source is being enumerated), here is an example:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectTwo<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> selector)
    {
        bool first_item_got = false;

        TSource first_item = default(TSource);

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (first_item_got)
            {
                yield return selector(first_item, item);
            }
            else
            {
                first_item = item;
            }

            first_item_got = !first_item_got;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the source sequence has an indexer, i.e. at minimum is `IReadOnlyList<T>` (array, list as mentioned in the question), and the idea is to split the sequence on consecutive pairs (which is not quite clear from the question), then it can be done simply like this

```
var pairs = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count / 2)
    .Select(i => Tuple.Create(list[2 * i], list[2 * i + 1]));
```